# How does ServiceBus work?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, nservicebus, servicebus

I'm interested in how does ServiceBus working. I mean not concrete realization, but **general idea**, pattern if possible to say this way.
Is it encapsulated Observer logic inside? Maybe someone knew the articles like "Create your own ServiceBus tuturial" or "Create own ServiceBus for dummies" =)

Comment: I suggest you check out the website [documentation](http://www.nservicebus.com/Documentation.aspx) and videos

Comment: current link to documentation http://docs.particular.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, I asked that question a lot of time ago, but no one still get an simple and correct answer. ServiceBus normally work in pretty much straightforward manner - hide transport layer inside and allow to publishers transfer their data (message) through this transport layer, and guarantee that subscribers will get this information. Message queue is used as transport layer most of the time. Sometimes some additional bussines logic could be added to servicebus implementation, like invoking routing between subscribers, or security, or some other things, but in general it's just an abstraction above transport layer.

So you can see that it's pretty simple inside.

Answer (score 1):

nServiceBus is one of the implementations. However, Udi is quite good at explaining things.

Look at these videos: http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/06/08/NNUGPresentationUdiDahanOnNServiceBus.aspx